# Strip all non numbers but decimal in a delimited data set in PERL

Tags: regex, perl

I have a data set that has a delimiter and I like to remove all non numerical data but keep the decimal point if it has one.

I can't figure out how to include the decimal itself since right now it strips it with this:

```
$output =~ s/[^0-9|\|]*//gi;
```

A sample of the output is:
    38.1mm|1013.88s|81%|22°

So I want to see: `38.1|1013.88|81|22`

Thanks

Comment: you don't need | inside [] ... the "or" is implied... that's what a character class is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output =~ s/[^\d.|]+//g;
```

This will remove any characters other than digits, `.`, or `|`.

Comment: I think adding a + would make it faster

Comment: @JoelFan It's not necessary, because of the `g` flag, but I don't know that much Perl, so I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!  I kept trying to use the | with the dot and failed, then I tried variations of that, then looking at it now, I realised I forgot the delimiter itself in my original tests... Oops.

Comment: @p.s.w.g it will work without the + but it will be faster with it because the regex will process multiple characters at once instead of one at a time

Answer (score 4):

The transliterate operator [tr///](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) can delete characters:

```
$output =~ tr/0-9.|//cd;
```